# Select distinct name and number from a table and show it to the drop down box, then save how can i do?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I want to select distinct `name` and `number` from a table and show it to the drop down box, then save. how can I do?

I tried this code but I didn't get the output:

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT DISTINCT id, number,name FROM %I WHERE aed!=$1  AND dept_code=$2', 'table_name_xxx') USING 'D',dept_code;
```

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In this case you have provided virtually nothing to work with. A single select statement which may or may not actually work is completely insufficant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to select distinct `name` and `number` ...

It's not entirely clear, what you ask. You want distinct combinations `(name, number)`?
In any case, while you have `id` in the `SELECT` list (assuming that's the PK), the result is *all rows*. Try without:

```
SELECT DISTINCT number, name FROM  ...
```

Comment: Please do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and aim for clearer questions.